# Docker php:apache HTML/PHP code runs incorrectly. stack main() thrown in multiple areas

Tags: php, docker, docker-swarm

thanks for taking some time to read over this question. I have code written in PHP, HTML, CSS,
Javascript and MySQL on a development computer. this code runs fine. No errors shown.

I wanted to move my code to a docker swarm. I made a docker compose file (FIG 1) and launched
to my docker swarm *specs shown*(FIG 2). the swarm stack runs perfectly but when i went to add
my code to the volume connected to /var/www/html it shows incorrectly with error upon error
(FIG 3).

*I have tried to provide any valuable information to crack this question. If there is anything i
am missing or if there is too much info?!? Let me know.*

Thanks in advance.

### Docker (FIG 1 && FIG 2)

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  loadbalancer:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    deploy:
      mode: global
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

  web:
    image: php:8.0-rc-apache-buster
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - backend
    deploy:
      mode: global
    volumes:
      - ./code:/var/www/html/
      - ./apache2.conf:/var/apache2/apache2.conf

  mariadb:
    image: linuxserver/mariadb:arm32v7-latest
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./data:/config/databases
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname==dot5

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=mariadb
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    deploy:
      mode: global
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:


Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 3
  Running: 3
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 11
 Server Version: 19.03.13
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: active
  NodeID: 101slznkwl25s4pejtngbrq0z
  Is Manager: true
  ClusterID: jphdf0tzm4p37i7xail1mcoiq
  Managers: 4
  Nodes: 8
  Default Address Pool: 10.0.0.0/8  
  SubnetSize: 24
  Data Path Port: 4789
  Orchestration:
   Task History Retention Limit: 5
  Raft:
   Snapshot Interval: 10000
   Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
   Heartbeat Tick: 1
   Election Tick: 10
  Dispatcher:
   Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
  CA Configuration:
   Expiry Duration: 3 months
   Force Rotate: 0
  Autolock Managers: false
  Root Rotation In Progress: false
  Node Address: 192.168.0.109
  Manager Addresses:
   192.168.0.102:2377
   192.168.0.103:2377
   192.168.0.109:2377
   192.168.0.86:2377
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.4.51-v7+
 Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: armv7l
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 975.4MiB
 Name: dot3
 ID: UZO6:MLFS:W2AW:EFAI:2KXY:XQNE:3K2S:CEND:JQCY:EVVH:HEEW:ICOM
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
WARNING: No kernel memory TCP limit support
WARNING: No oom kill disable support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
```

### PHP code (FIG 3)

```
<div class='row justify-content-center mart' id="items">
<!-- connect -->
<?php
include_once 'con.php';
global $conn;
$filter = "";

if (isset($_GET['all'])) {
  $filter = "";
}
else if (isset($_GET['household'])) {
  $filter = "WHERE type = 'household'";
}
else if (isset($_GET['weed'])) {
  $filter = "WHERE type = 'weed'";
}
else if (isset($_GET['garden'])) {
  $filter = "WHERE type = 'garden'";
}
else if (isset($_GET['dessert'])) {
  $filter = "WHERE type = 'dessert'";
}
else if (isset($_GET['tech'])) {
  $filter = "WHERE type = 'tech'";
}
else if (isset($_GET['bants'])) {
  $filter = "WHERE type = 'bants'";
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM items $filter";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-12 mb-4">
    <a href="<?php printf('%s?item_id=%s', 'view.php', $row['item_id'])?>">
    <div class='menu_item sharp-rounded slight-hover'>
      <div class="card-img-top-left">
        <i <?php echo 'class="fas fa-'.$row['fa'].' fa-2x text-orange"'; ?>></i>
      </div>
        <img class='menu-img sharp-rounded marb' style="max-height: 600px; max-width: 100%; width: auto;" id="loading-item" src='<?php echo str_replace("../", "assets/", $row["image"]);?>' alt='<?php echo $row['name']; ?>'>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-6 mart">
            <h4 style="color: #e84545;">$<?php echo $row['price']; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mart text-orange">
            <a href="view.php?item_id=<?php echo $row['item_id']; ?>#add_to_cart">Add To Cart</a>
          </div>
          <div class="inline-block" style="width: 100%;">
            <h4><?php echo $row['name'];?></h4>
            <p style="color:#686E79; overflow: hidden;
            display: -webkit-box;
            -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;">
              <?php echo $row['info']; ?>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<?php
}} else { ?>
  <div class="bob"><img class="sharp-rounded" src="assets/images/gen/nothing_here.png" alt="nothing here!" width="70%"></div>
<?php
} mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</div>
```

Expectied look of the site. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2NxH.png): docker-stack  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO6T5.png): rpi development server

[docker-stack look/feel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2NxH.png)

[rpi dev server look/feel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO6T5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved.

It turns out that mysqli is required to make my application run (it is not installed by default!).

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The Docker image you are using for your web container at least does not have the mysqli plugin enabled(hence the undefined function). You can enable that in a Dockerfile using `docker-php-ext-install` and `docker-php-ext-enable` in the official PHP base image.

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/php#php-core-extensions

https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/391

Once that is resolved, there may be other issues, but that is the immediate problem.

Comment: i have done that. please check the updated information. Thanks.

Comment: @OwenBramley where is the updated information? I am not seeing any updates on your question.

Comment: should be there. images at the bottom ;)

Comment: Can you view the source of the output? The message at the top is due the headers already having been sent before the session is initialized. The failure to initialize the session is causing the subsequent errors. Likely there is another error or warning that is being output before. As soon as output is written, the headers are sent which means the session cookie cannot be sent.

Comment: I deleted the session_start function from the top of my index.php

Comment: The code provided still doesn't match the screenshots the least... and sessions in a stateless environment require another (shared) backend, instead of the (stateful) local file-system. The load-balancer is a clear indicator for that.

Comment: @MartinZeitler could you elaborate?

Comment: @OwenBramley sessions by default store data on the local filesystem. If you have multiple nodes and use the local filesystem for storage, your sessions will not be synchronized across nodes. Generally this is handled by using a custom session handler to store data in an external location(i.e. Redis or a database). This is not likely part of the immediate issue, but will need to be addressed(among other things) for this to be a production-ready installation.